# Is there a hidden location-type property for TropicalStormData?

Tags: curated-data, geography

`TropicalStormData` gives you time-series data on tropical storms.  In the property list there is not a location (geographic coordinates) property listed.  There are sometimes *hidden* properties that the savvy gurus know how to get to.

Is there a location-type property that will give time-series for storms?  I am looking to get a time-series of the location of the eye of the storm.

Also, a geographic region for the cone that forecast it location from that time would be nice to have as well.

Comment: What is the location supposed to indicate, where the eye of the storm was at that given moment?

Comment: @J. M. Correct.  The location of the storm at that date (or date time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it seems there is no hidden `GeoPosition`-type property for `TropicalStormData` you can get this information from the USA [National Hurricane Centre GIS Data](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/).  There you can download both [SHP](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/SHP.html) and [KML](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/KML.html) files for current and historical storms that can be used with `Import`. These have the coordinates, prediction cones, and more information for the storms.

Comment: That's very useful; thank you for posting this followup! (+1)